# Can anyone help finish this proof? Induction proof $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and odd $k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

The question is prove $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and odd $k$.  I got as far as:

Notice for $n=1$, $2^{1+2}= 8 \mid k^2-1.$ Also notice for an odd $k$ when $n=1$, thus $k^{2}-1=(k-1)(k+1)$. Hence, $k-1$ and $k+1$ is divisible by $4$ and the other of those expressions is divisible by $2$. Since $2$ and $4$ are integers, we can then conclude that the equality is true for $n=1$.

Now suppose it's true for some $n=a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

\begin{align*}
2^{a+2} \mid k^{2^a} -1 \\
2^{a}\cdot 4 \mid k^{2^a} -1\\
.\\
.\\
. \\
2^{a+3} \mid k^{2^{a}}\cdot k^{2} -1 \\
2^{a+3} \mid k^{2^{a+1}} -1 \\
\end{align*}

Thus, by induction $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and odd $k$.

I Need help solving for the "..."  Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange.  It seems that your list is not correct.  $2^{a+2}=2^a2^2=4\cdot2^a$

Comment: @barak manos: it does work for $k=3$ and $n=1$

Comment: Is my answer satisfactory?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts. If they are no longer satisfactory, then you have the option to delete them, but please don't abuse this possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the induction step is $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1\Rightarrow 2^{n+3} \mid k^{2^{n+1}} -1$

But $k^{2^{n+1}} -1=k^{2^n\cdot2} -1=(k^{2^n})^2 -1=(k^{2^n}-1)(k^{2^n}+1)$

The first factor is divisible by $2^{n+2}$ by using the hypothesis of induction and the right factor is even. Which was to be proved.

Comment: Awesome! i appreciate it!

Comment: how would i end the proof? ^{a+3} &\mid k^{2^a \cdot 2} -1 \\
2^{a+3} \mid (k^{2^{a}})^2  -1 \\
2^{a+3} \mid (k^{2^{a}}-1)(k^{2^{a}}+1) -1 \\
2^{a+3} \mid k^{2^{a+1}} -1 \\
\end{align*}
Thus, by induction $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1$ for all $n \geq 1$ and odd $k$.

Comment: Can you fix your Latex? I don't understand anything.

Comment: I got through all the way to 2^(n+3) | (k^(2^n) -1)(k^(2^n) +1). is that the end of the proof? or what do we need to assume

Comment: Yes. You proved that $P(1)$ is true and $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ for $n\ge 1$, where $P(n)$ is $2^{n+2} \mid k^{2^n} -1$. This is all that induction requires.

Answer (score 0):

I would prove first this factorisation, valid for any $k$:
$$k^{2^n-1}=(k^2-1)(k^2+1)(k^{2^2}+1)(k^{2^3}+1)\dotsm(k^{2^{n-1}}+1),$$
based on the relation $\;(k^{2^{n-1}})^2=k^{2^n}$.

Now  each of the last $n-1$ factors is divisible by $2$, hence their product is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

As to  the first factor, it is  divisible by $2^3\;$ if $k$ is odd. Indeed, if $k=2i+1$, we have
$$(2i+1)^2-1=4i^2+4i=4i(i+1),$$
and $i(i+1)$ is even.